# Loading a table into PostgreSQL with a foreign key produces an error

Tags: xml, postgresql, foreign-keys

I am using SymmetricDS database replication software to replicate tables across databases.

I have this XML defined table for PostgreSQL which I've created:

```
<table name="ServiceItem">
  <column name="ServiceItemID" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true"/>
  <column name="ParentItemID"  type="INTEGER" />

  <foreign-key name="FK_ServiceItem_ServiceItem" foreignTable="ServiceItem">
      <reference local="ServiceItemID" foreign="ParentItemID" />
  </foreign-key>
</table>
```

I expect that all `parentItemID` values MUST exist in the `ServiceItemID` column, that's the point of a foreign key.

But I get this error from SymmetricDS when I load it:

```
[] - JdbcSqlTemplate - ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys 
for referenced table "ServiceItem".  Failed to execute: ALTER TABLE "ServiceItem"
ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_ServiceItem_ServiceItem" FOREIGN KEY ("ServiceItemID") 
REFERENCES "ServiceItem" ("ParentItemID")
```

If I remove the foreign key, everything works as expected.  This error message is confusing me and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  What does it mean?

Comment: To me it looks like you have them flipped: `ParentItemID referencing  ServiceItem (ServiceItemID) ` is the normal way to discribe hierarchies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be the other way around:

```
<table name="ServiceItem">
  <column name="ServiceItemID" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true"/>
  <column name="ParentItemID"  type="INTEGER" />

  <foreign-key name="FK_ServiceItem_ServiceItem" foreignTable="ServiceItem">
      <reference local="ParentItemID" foreign="ServiceItemID" />
  </foreign-key>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In postgresql, if you want to create a Foreign key you must obey each of these rules:

1. A FOREIGN KEY constraint must refer to a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint.
2. The two key fields must have the compatible data type.
3. Must have REFERENCES privilege on both the referencing and referenced tables.

I happen to have disobeyed the first one, the key I am referring to was not unique.

Here is some helpful documentation on how to use foreign keys: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

So there are two solutions, either enforce `ParentItemID` as a unique column, or flip the foreign keys so the primary unique key becomes the foreign reference.

I flipped ParentItemID and ServiceItemID so that the unique one is the target and the non-unique is the column that is constrained.

```
<table name="ServiceItem">
  <column name="ServiceItemID" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true"/>
  <column name="ParentItemID"  type="INTEGER" />

  <foreign-key name="FK_ServiceItem_ServiceItem" foreignTable="ServiceItem">
      <reference local="ParentItemID" foreign="ServiceItemID" />
  </foreign-key>
</table>
```